# Get updated post meta on post_updated action

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get the submitted post meta on the post_updated action via the function get_post_meta().

However it only returns the old metadata, before I clicked the "Save" button. Probably because the new meta wasn't saved to the database yet.

Is there any way to get the new metadata inside the getMeta function below?

```
add_action('post_updated', 'getMeta', 10, 1);

function getMeta($post_id) {
    if($post->post_status != 'trash'){

        $meta = get_post_meta($post_id);

        echo '<pre>'; print_r($meta); echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Edit: I have to use the post_updated action for other operations, which aren't displayed in the above code example. So using an other action is unfortunately not an option :(

Answer (score 1):

You're hooking to wrong action, try something like

```
add_action('updated_postmeta', 'getMeta', 10, 4);

function getMeta($meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value) 
{
    if($post->post_status != 'trash')
    {
       // do you magic here   
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
I forgot to mention that I need the post_updated action for other operations, which I didn't include in the above code example for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Are they needed for your post meta manipulation and have to be in same function?

Comment: It is something needed for synchronizing posts, pages and products between blogs on a multisite install.

It would be awesome to find a way to get the metadata in the post_updated action, because it seems very intuitive to me, that you would be able to get all the data of the post after you clicked "save" instead of just half of it :)

Comment: The action is [updated_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/updated_meta_type_meta/) in case anyone interested. (Or if you want to catch the old meta value, then you will need the [update_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/) action.